# How do I get an image in my listview?

Tags: java, android, json, listview

Currently I'm using an `ArrayAdapter` which I just import. As the question states I want to get images into my listviews. I'm loading information into my list using JSONObjects and storing them into my ArrayLists. I know my current method removes html tages from the JSONObjects.

public class Home extends Activity {

```
ListView lView;
TextView tView;
ArrayAdapter lAdapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
    lView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    //tView = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.);
    loadList(lView);



}

public void loadList(ListView lView){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall("URL", ServiceHandler.GET);

    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> body = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


            // Getting JSON Array node
            JSONArray entries = jsonObj.getJSONArray("entries"); 
            for (int i = 0; i < entries.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = entries.getJSONObject(i);
                String text = c.getString("introtext"); 
                if(text == "null"){
                    text = "No text here" + "\n" + "\n";

                }
                else {
                    text = android.text.Html.fromHtml(text).toString();
                }
                String title= c.getString("title");
                String full = title + "\n" + "\n" + text;
                titles.add(full);
                //body.add(text);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
    }

    lAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
    lView.setAdapter(lAdapter);
}
```

}

Any suggestions would be great help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a layout same what you want to show in a row, now create a class for a custom adapter like:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<T>{
}
```

Where T represents the entity class, which represents your data model.
Now under override method:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {}
```

Inflate your layout created for the row, and set each view as you want to show.
Don't forgot to use lazy loading for the image to load over the imageview.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom adapter that has your own Layout defined.  In this layout, you can include whatever you want (including an ImageView, that you can place your image).

There are many examples, but the important thing to know in your code, is you will supply your own adapter here, and set it up a bit differently:

```
lAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_custom_adapter, titles);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Try to use a `Base Adapter`
- Inflate a custom Xml having a `imageview`  using the `base adapter`
- You can put any views(Image,textview etc ) depending on your
  requirement
- Finally use `picasso` or `imageloader` to populate images using the JSON
  response to your base adapter

**Hope it helps**, *Revert back to me if you need any more help*, **Happy coding**

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a custom adapter instead of `ArrayAdapter`, so that you can use your own layout for every row, and perform any 'image loading' there. Try creating a class that extends the [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) abstract class from the framework. Also, search the web or here (in stackoverflow) you'll find tons of tutorials on how to create a custom adapter.

Since downloading and loading images can be a bit of a pain if you aren't experienced with ListViews and custom adapters, I would suggest looking up two 3rd party libraries for this job:
[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), each one having examples on how to use them alongside with custom adapters